# how to use privileged helper tool(installed using SMJobless) to launch other application in root privileges on osx

Tags: objective-c, macos, root, smjobbless

I have a application inside which i have kept other applications.I want to launch other application in root privilege through main application.As we know `AuthorizationExecuteWithPrivileges()` has been deprecated, so that i have created a privileged helper tool. I am using Main application to install this helper tool through `SMJobBless()` function , and communicate through `XPC` mechanism. Every thing is working fine, Main application sending message(Path of application to be launch) to helper tool that is already running in root mode. The helper tool is able to launch that application provided in path, **but the problem is, launched application doesn't have root privilege**. Can anyone tell me **how i can use this helper tool to launch another application in root privilege**.Or is there any other mechanism to achieve it, i will ever thankful for this.

Comment: Hey, is the Helper tool that perform privileged tasks.. not the main app...

Comment: yes, helper tool run as root

Comment: So your code must be there...